# How to upload Android Retrofit with key param?

Tags: android, video, upload, retrofit

Please help me.
I have using retrofit to upload video.

```
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://youdo.vn";

    public interface FileUploadService {

        @Multipart
        @POST("/uploadVideo")
        ApiResult uploadFile(@Part("file") TypedFile resource, @Query("path") String path, @Part("site_name")String site,Callback<String> cb);

        @Multipart
        @POST("/upload/uploadVideo")
        void uploadFile(@Body MultipartTypedOutput attachments,Callback<String> cb);

        @Multipart
        @POST("/upload/uploadVideo")
        void uploadFile(@PartMap Map<String,TypedFile> params,Callback<String> cb);

        @Multipart
        @POST("/upload/uploadVideo")
        ApiResult uploadFile(@Part("") TypedFile resource);
}
}
```

My issue: server using filed key is videos to get video post to server.

I don't post video to server please help me.

I used Postman for upload then upload success to server.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsbX9.png

thanks for support.

Comment: server response code 500.
or json format invalid start with '$'
server using query for get videos from post. and retrofit using path for post :(

Comment: thanks Shubham,
I have changed solution to using HTTP.
Because Retrofit can't upload file big size :(